# Configure specific warning to report as error using jshint and jenkins checkstyle-plugin

Tags: javascript, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, checkstyle, jshint

I'm using Jenkins with [checkstyle-plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/x/GYCGAQ) and JSHint.

I want to be able to configure a specific warning to be reported as error.
Apparently I would need to use a config xml file for checkstyle, but I've searched for this file and couldn't find it.

I've gone through the [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/checkstyle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/checkstyle/rules/CheckStyleRules.java) but still couldn't figure out where do I need to put it.

Is that the correct way to do it? If so, where should be the file location?

Comment: How do you invoke Checkstyle? Is it Gradle, Maven or something else? The Checkstyle Jenkins plug-in just scans for checkstyle-result.xml files in the build workspace and reports the number of warnings found.

Comment: I'm using this command line to run jshint:

"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" jshint -c .jshintrc --reporter=checkstyle app/ > jshint_checkstyle.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkstyle will not be started by Jenkins itself - the Jenkins checkstyle plugin will only take the results of a checkstyle run and integrate it into what Jenkins displays as results for your project.

When working with Jenkins most people use tools like maven, gradle, ant etc.
For maven (for example) you would define the checkstyle plugin as follows:

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <configLocation>checkstyle-config.xml</configLocation>
        <checkstyleXmlOutput>true</checkstyleXmlOutput>
        <checkstyleXmlOutputDirectory>target/site</checkstyleXmlOutputDirectory>
        <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
        <failsOnError>false</failsOnError>
        <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
        <excludes>**/module-info.java,**/package-info.java</excludes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

  </plugins>
<//reporting>
```

My personal `checkstyle-config.xml` looks like (depending on my perosnal needs):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN" "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
<module name="Checker">
  <property name="severity" value="warning"/>

  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <!-- Annotations -->
    <module name="AnnotationLocation"/>
    <!-- <module name="AnnotationOnSameLine"/> -->
    <module name="AnnotationUseStyle"/>
    <module name="MissingDeprecated"/>
    <module name="MissingOverride"/>
    <module name="PackageAnnotation"/>
    <module name="SuppressWarnings"/>
    <module name="SuppressWarningsHolder"/>

    <!-- Block Checks -->
    <module name="AvoidNestedBlocks">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="EmptyBlock">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="option" value="text"/>
    </module>
    <module name="EmptyCatchBlock"/>
    <module name="LeftCurly">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="option" value="nl"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="CLASS_DEF, CTOR_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_SWITCH, LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED, LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_WHILE, METHOD_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NeedBraces">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="RightCurly">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="option" value="alone"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE, CLASS_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_WHILE, LITERAL_DO"/>
    </module>

    <!-- Class Design -->
    <module name="DesignForExtension"/>
    <module name="FinalClass">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="HideUtilityClassConstructor">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="InnerTypeLast"/>
    <module name="InterfaceIsType">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MutableException"/>
    <module name="OneTopLevelClass"/>
    <module name="ThrowsCount">
      <property name="max" value="6"/>
    </module>
    <module name="VisibilityModifier">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>

    <!-- Coding -->
    <!-- <module name="ArrayTrailingComma"/> -->
    <!-- <module name="AvoidInlineConditionals"/> -->
    <module name="CovariantEquals"/>
    <module name="DeclarationOrder"/>
    <module name="DefaultComesLast"/>
    <module name="EmptyStatement">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="EqualsAvoidNull"/>
    <module name="EqualsHashCode">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="ExplicitInitialization"/>
    <module name="FallThrough"/>
    <module name="FinalLocalVariable"/>
    <module name="HiddenField">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="ignoreConstructorParameter" value="true"/>
      <property name="ignoreSetter" value="true"/>
      <property name="setterCanReturnItsClass" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <!-- TODO Enable later
    <module name="IllegalCatch"/>
    -->
    <module name="IllegalInstantiation">
      <property name="classes" value="java.lang.Boolean"/>
    </module>
    <module name="IllegalThrows"/>
    <module name="IllegalToken"/>
    <module name="IllegalTokenText"/>
    <module name="IllegalType"/>
    <module name="InnerAssignment">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <!-- TODO Enable later
    <module name="MagicNumber">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    -->
    <!-- <module name="MissingCtor"/> -->
    <module name="MissingSwitchDefault">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="ModifiedControlVariable"/>
    <!-- TODO Enable later
    <module name="MultipleStringLiterals"/>
    -->
    <module name="MultipleVariableDeclarations"/>
    <module name="NestedForDepth">
      <property name="max" value="3"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NestedIfDepth">
      <property name="max" value="4"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NestedTryDepth">
      <property name="max" value="2"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NoClone"/>
    <module name="NoFinalizer"/>
    <module name="OneStatementPerLine"/>
    <module name="OverloadMethodsDeclarationOrder"/>
    <module name="PackageDeclaration"/>
    <module name="ParameterAssignment"/>
    <!-- <module name="RequireThis"/> -->
    <module name="ReturnCount">
      <property name="max" value="7"/>
      <!-- <property name="maxForVoid" value="2"/> -->
    </module>
    <module name="SimplifyBooleanExpression">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SimplifyBooleanReturn">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="StringLiteralEquality"/>
    <module name="SuperClone"/>
    <module name="SuperFinalize"/>
    <!-- <module name="UnnecessaryParentheses"/> -->
    <module name="VariableDeclarationUsageDistance"/>

    <!-- Imports -->
    <module name="AvoidStarImport">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <!-- <module name="AvoidStaticImport"/> -->
    <!-- <module name="CustomImportOrder"/> -->
    <module name="IllegalImport">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <!-- <module name="ImportControl"/> -->
    <!-- <module name="ImportOrder"/> -->
    <module name="RedundantImport">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="UnusedImports">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>

    <!-- Javadoc Comments -->
    <module name="AtclauseOrder"/>
    <module name="JavadocMethod">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <!-- <module name="JavadocParagraph"/> -->
    <!-- <module name="JavadocStyle"/> -->
    <!-- <module name="JavadocTagContinuationIndentation"/> -->
    <module name="JavadocType">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocVariable">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NonEmptyAtclauseDescription"/>
    <module name="SingleLineJavadoc"/>
    <module name="SummaryJavadocCheck"/>
    <!-- <module name="WriteTag"/> -->

    <!-- Metrics -->
    <!-- <module name="BooleanExpressionComplexity"/> -->
    <!-- <module name="ClassDataAbstractionCoupling"/> -->
    <!-- <module name="ClassFanOutComplexity"/> -->
    <!-- <module name="CyclomaticComplexity"/> -->
    <!-- <module name="JavaNCSS"/> -->
    <!-- <module name="NPathComplexity"/> -->

    <!-- Miscellaneous -->
    <module name="ArrayTypeStyle">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="AvoidEscapedUnicodeCharacters"/>
    <module name="CommentsIndentation"/>
    <!-- <module name="DescendantToken"/> -->
    <module name="FinalParameters">
      <property name="tokens" value="METHOD_DEF,CTOR_DEF,LITERAL_CATCH"/>
    </module>
    <!-- TODO
    <module name="Indentation">
      <property name="basicOffset" value="2"/>
      <property name="braceAdjustment" value="1"/>
      <property name="caseIndent" value="2"/>
      <property name="throwsIndent" value="2"/>
      <property name="arrayInitIndent" value="2"/>
      <property name="lineWrappingIndentation" value="2"/>
    </module>
    -->
    <module name="OuterTypeFilename"/>
    <!--
    <module name="TodoComment">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    -->
    <!--
    <module name="TrailingComment"/>
    -->
    <module name="UncommentedMain"/>
    <module name="UpperEll">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>

    <!-- Modifiers -->
    <module name="ModifierOrder">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="RedundantModifier">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>

    <!-- Naming Conventions -->
    <!-- <module name="AbbreviationAsWordInName"/> -->
    <module name="AbstractClassName"/>
    <module name="CatchParameterName"/>
    <module name="ClassTypeParameterName"/>
    <module name="ConstantName">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="InterfaceTypeParameterName"/>
    <module name="LocalFinalVariableName">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="LocalVariableName">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MemberName">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MethodName">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MethodTypeParameterName"/>
    <module name="PackageName">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="ParameterName">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="StaticVariableName">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="TypeName">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>

    <!-- Regexp -->
    <!-- <module name="Regexp"/> -->
    <!-- <module name="RegexpSinglelineJava"/> -->

    <!-- Size Violations -->
    <module name="AnonInnerLength">
      <property name="max" value="100"/>
    </module>
    <!-- <module name="ExecutableStatementCount"/> -->
    <module name="LineLength">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="max" value="3100"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MethodCount">
      <property name="maxTotal" value="110"/>
      <property name="maxPublic" value="110"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MethodLength">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="max" value="260"/>
    </module>
    <module name="OuterTypeNumber"/>
    <module name="ParameterNumber">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="max" value="31"/>
    </module>

    <!-- Whitespace  -->
    <module name="EmptyForInitializerPad"/>
    <module name="EmptyForIteratorPad">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="EmptyLineSeparator">
      <property name="allowMultipleEmptyLinesInsideClassMembers" value="false"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="IMPORT, CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF, STATIC_INIT, INSTANCE_INIT, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, VARIABLE_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="GenericWhitespace"/>
    <module name="MethodParamPad"/>
    <module name="NoLineWrap">
      <property name="tokens" value="IMPORT, PACKAGE_DEF"/> <!-- TODO , STATIC_IMPORT -->
    </module>
    <module name="NoWhitespaceAfter">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="ARRAY_INIT, INC, DEC, UNARY_MINUS, UNARY_PLUS, BNOT, LNOT, DOT, TYPECAST, ARRAY_DECLARATOR, INDEX_OP"/> <!-- TODO , AT, METHOD_REF -->
    </module>
    <module name="NoWhitespaceBefore">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="COMMA, SEMI, POST_INC, POST_DEC, DOT, GENERIC_START, GENERIC_END"/> <!-- TODO , ELLIPSIS, METHOD_REF -->
    </module>
    <module name="OperatorWrap">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="tokens" value=""/>
    </module>
    <module name="ParenPad">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="ANNOTATION, ANNOTATION_FIELD_DEF, CTOR_CALL, CTOR_DEF, ENUM_CONSTANT_DEF, EXPR, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_NEW, LITERAL_SWITCH, LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED, LITERAL_WHILE, METHOD_CALL, METHOD_DEF, QUESTION, RESOURCE_SPECIFICATION, SUPER_CTOR_CALL"/> <!-- TODO , LAMBDA, DOT -->
    </module>
    <module name="SeparatorWrap">
      <property name="option" value="eol"/>
      <property name="tokens" value=""/>
    </module>
    <!-- TODO
    <module name="SingleSpaceSeparator"/>
    -->
    <module name="TypecastParenPad"/>
    <module name="WhitespaceAfter">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="WhitespaceAround">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="ASSIGN,BAND,BAND_ASSIGN,BOR,BOR_ASSIGN,BSR,BSR_ASSIGN,BXOR,BXOR_ASSIGN,COLON,DIV,DIV_ASSIGN,DO_WHILE,EQUAL,GE,GT,LAMBDA,LAND,LCURLY,LE,LITERAL_ASSERT,LITERAL_CATCH,LITERAL_DO,LITERAL_ELSE,LITERAL_FINALLY,LITERAL_FOR,LITERAL_IF,LITERAL_RETURN,LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED,LITERAL_TRY,LITERAL_WHILE,LOR,LT,MINUS,MINUS_ASSIGN,MOD,MOD_ASSIGN,NOT_EQUAL,PLUS,PLUS_ASSIGN,QUESTION,RCURLY,SL,SLIST,SL_ASSIGN,SR,SR_ASSIGN,STAR,STAR_ASSIGN,TYPE_EXTENSION_AND"/>
    </module>

  </module>

  <!-- Headers -->
   <module name="RegexpHeader">
    <property name="header" value="^/\*\n \* Copyright \(C\) (\d\d\d\d)(-(\d\d\d\d))?(,(\d\d\d\d)(-(\d\d\d\d))?)* Dipl.-Inform. Kai Hofmann. All rights reserved!\n \*/$"/>
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/>
  </module>

  <!-- Javadocs -->
  <!-- <module name="JavadocPackage"/> -->

  <!-- Misc -->
  <module name="NewlineAtEndOfFile">
    <property name="lineSeparator" value="lf"/>
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java,xml,dtd,properties,txt"/>
  </module>
  <module name="Translation"/>
  <module name="UniqueProperties"/>

  <!-- Regexp -->
  <!-- <module name="RegexpMultiline"/> -->
  <!-- <module name="RegexpOnFilename"/> -->
  <!-- <module name="RegexpSingleline"/> -->

  <!-- Size violations -->
  <module name="FileLength">
    <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    <property name="max" value="20000"/>
  </module>

  <!-- Whitespace -->
  <module name="FileTabCharacter">
    <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java,xml,dtd"/>
  </module>

</module>
```

Also I am using a Jenkinsfile (declartive pipeline) with the following stage to start the checkstyle via maven:

```
stage('Sanity check')
 {
  steps
   {
    script
     {
      if (isUnix()) 
       {           
        sh 'mvn --batch-mode checkstyle:checkstyle'
       }
      else
       {
        bat 'mvn --batch-mode checkstyle:checkstyle'
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

For embedding JSHint, please have a look at [How to configure JSHint with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802243/how-to-configure-jshint-with-maven)